# What do I change to make it start in the bottom left rather than the bottom right?

Tags: css

I came across this [codepen](http://codepen.io/kzf/pen/LEEzew?editors=1100) with a diagonal fill div on hover, my question is how do I start the fill from the bottom left instead of the bottom right, this maybe a simple task but I have no idea, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
.diagonal {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #67809F;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0px;
  }

.diagonal:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500%;
    height: 1000%;
    background: #34495E;
    z-index: -1;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translateX(calc(20% - 25px)) translateY(10%) rotate(-45deg);
    /transform: translateY(10%) translateX(16%) rotate(-45deg);
    transition: transform .3s;
  }

.diagonal:hover::after {
    transform: translateY(10%) translateX(-25px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
```

http://codepen.io/kzf/pen/LEEzew?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `translateY(10%)` to `translateY(0%)` on both the original and hover states

https://jsfiddle.net/nko2u23j/

```css
.demo {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 150px;
}

.mt {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.small {
  width: 120px;
}

.medium {
  width: 160px;
}

.large {
  width: 230px;
}

.extra-large {
  width: 360px;
}

.diagonal {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #67809F;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0px;
}
.diagonal:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500%;
  height: 1000%;
  background: #34495E;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translateX(-25px) translateY(0%) rotate(-45deg);
  /transform: translateY(10%) translateX(16%) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform .3s;
}
.diagonal:hover::after {
  transform: translateY(0%) translateX(calc(20% - 25px)) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  
  <button class="mt small diagonal">Click me!</button>
  <br>
  <button class="mt medium diagonal">Click me!</button>
  <br>
  <button class="mt large diagonal">Click me!</button>
  <br>
  <button class="mt extra-large diagonal">Click me!</button>

</div>
```